# Объясните, пожалуйста, что происходит в приведённом ниже коде (Room)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-sqlite

С Room работаю недавно, поэтому, когда вижу примеры кода, иногда не могу до конца понять происходящее.
В связи с этим у меня несколько вопросов:

1. Почему, в этом случае, работа с DAO осуществляется с помощью функции, хотя в другом примере (код приведу ниже) это делалось с помощью переменных
2. Всё то, что происходит внутри `companion object` - это указание на то, что база данных берётся из самого проекта или есть что-то ещё?
3. Правильно ли я понимаю, что `"app_database"` - это имя базы данных? И, если это так, то почему оно не совпадает с названием файла базы данных?
4. Что за переменные `INSTANCE`и `instance`? И почему `instance` в конце кода просто написано без каких либо действий с ним?

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Schedule::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun scheduleDao(): ScheduleDao

    companion object { // аналог static в java
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    "app_database")
                    .createFromAsset("database/bus_schedule.db")
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance

                instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Другой пример:

```
@Database(entities = [CardModel::class, MedicationsModel::class, OrderLocalModel::class], version = 1)
abstract class DataBasePharmacy : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val cardDao: CardDao
    abstract val medicationsDao: MedicationsDao
    abstract val orderLocalDao: OrderLocalDao
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. преобразование kotlin кода в java код при кодогенерации позволяет такое писать, итоговый код будет одинаков.
2. Непонятно что вы спрашиваете. У вас там kotlin аналог статики из java, где база создаётся, видимо, из файла в проекте.
3. По идее да, имя должно быть и имененм файла. Возможно вас смущает то, что имя и имя файла не совпадают с именем файла в ассетах.
4. INSTANCE - статическое поле класса, а instance - локальная переменная в лямбде. В лямбдах kotlin можно опустить return, что вы и видите